# Why does WebStorm add `--set-upstream` when pushing during GitHub pull request

Tags: git, github, intellij-idea, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

I'm using `VCS -> Git -> Create Pull Request` functionality. Before the pull request is created I set the current `feature` branch to track `upstream`:

```
$ git branch -u upstream/feature
```

But after the pull request is created I check the branch and it tracks `origin`:

```
$ git branch -vv
* feature-5 3b5676ee [origin/feature-5] Implemented build for ...
```

I checked `VSC` log and I see the following:

```
... git -c ... push --progress --porcelain origin feature-5 --set-upstream
```

So WebStorm uses `--set-upstream` when pushing and that is what changes the tracking branch.

Why does it specify that option? Is there any way to disable it?

PS. I know what `--set-upstream` is for, the question is not about this parameter purpose.

Comment: I've added `intellij-idea` tag to have a bit better chances for JB staff to spot this question.

Comment: You might remove the `git` and `github` tags entirely, since your question is about why people who wrote software that isn't Git and isn't Gthub are doing things that are neither recommended nor controlled by Git or Github. :-)